# How to find number of vowels in each word of string?

Tags: python

```
s = input("Enter a sentence: ")
emp = ""
vow = 0
for i in s: 
    if i.isspace() == False:
        emp = emp+i
    else:
        for j in emp:
            if j in 'aeiouAEIOU':
                vow = vow+1
        print("The number of vowels in", emp, "are", vow)
        emp = ""
```

It only gives vowels for the first word.

Comment: I ran the code and it gives the vowels of all the words (just that the counter does not reset). Could you be more detailed on what is wrong?

Comment: What's the sentence given as input? What do you expect as output? Count of vowels per word, but in what form?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not working because the variable `vow` is never reset to 0. You should reset it for each new word you encounter, else it will print the total of vowels in your string.

---

A better solution is to make use of [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead of [`isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace), so words are "automatically" separated.

Then, you can iterate trough each word, and sum up letters which are vowels.

```
words = s.split()
for word in words:
    vow = sum(letter in 'aeiou' for letter in word.lower())
    print("The number of vowels in", word, "are", vow)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re` module for regular expressions.

```
import re

sentence = r'Hello World, how many vowels are in this sentence by word?'

for word in sentence.split():
    s = re.findall(r'[aeiou]', word, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(word,'has',len(s),'vowels.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sum` or `len` functions.

```
>>> s="asdf 14oji iii34"
>>> sum(1 for i in s if i in 'aeiouAEIOU')
6
>>>
```

or

```
>>> len([i for i in s if i in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
6
>>>
```

Comment: No need for `1`, boolean are treated as integer while summing. Moreover, it is better to use `.lower()` I think. But it prints total of voyels instead of voyels per word.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this way:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

for word in sentence.split():
    vowel_count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1

    print("The number of vowels in %s is: %d" % (word, vowel_count))
```