# Count vowels of each word in a string

Tags: python

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2JFq.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2JFq.png)

Hey, this is a program i want to write in python. I tried, and i sucessfully iterated words but now how do i count the individual score?

```
a_string = input("Enter a sentance: ").lower()
vowel_counts = {}
splits = a_string.split()
for i in splits:
    words = []
    words.append(i)
    print(words)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834818/how-to-find-number-of-vowels-in-each-word-of-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834818/how-to-find-number-of-vowels-in-each-word-of-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find number of vowels in each word of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834818/how-to-find-number-of-vowels-in-each-word-of-string)

Comment: I forgot to add the image sry now check the image, i have to give scores to individual words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flag the vowels using translate to convert all the vowels to 'a's .  Then count the 'a's in each word using the count method:

```
sentence = "computer programmers rock"

vowels  = str.maketrans("aeiouAEIOU","aaaaaaaaaa")
flagged = sentence.translate(vowels)                    # all vowels --> 'a'
counts  = [word.count('a') for word in flagged.split()] # counts per word
score   = sum(1 if c<=2 else 2 for c in counts)         # sum of points

print(counts,score)    
# [3, 3, 1] 5
```